# Aestan tray menu error - wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver

I am getting the error `Aestan Tray Menu` from the `WAMP` server.

The configuration file contains a syntax error:

> on line 0 [EParseError] No Tray icon was specified.
>
> Please assign a tray icon by using one of the TrayIcon* directives in
> the [Config]section

how can i fix it ?

Comment: please i relly need help

Comment: What did you change in the `wampmanager.tpl` or the `\wamp` folder between it working and it stopping working. It does not stop working without help from you.

Comment: You can read about the the issue by using the following links, you will get the idea what is going wrong. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,126657 http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608

Comment: @RiggsFolly - This actually isn't true - Windows Update kb3194496  broke this for me tonight.  Had been working for 6 months prior and with the new Windows 10 build it totally broke it.  Somehow the ini file was overwritten and the contents seemed blank - which is interesting.  Follow the threads in work with funs answer and this issue can be resolved by updating your wampmanager.ini with the details supplied in the thread.  I will also post the contents of the file here in a response.

Answer (score 29):

This is because the wampmanager.ini file is corrupted.

You can repair it without doing a full install.

1. Open up command crompt
2. Type "cd c:/wamp/scripts"
3. Type "php refresh.php" (note, for this step you'll need to have php as an environment path variable)

This should recreate wampmanager.ini and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this solves my wampserver error, after I run the "Wampserver update 3.2.0" was givin me the popup "aestan tray menu the configuration file contains a syntax error on line 11".

Comment: thanks a lot man, my case is a error pop up wafter switching language to Chinese, I solve it by running "/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php-win.exe refresh.php" in cmd in the scripts folder.

Comment: Worked like a magic,

Answer (score 1):

The threads at wampserver cover the issue - for me what fixed the problem was updating the wampmanager.ini with the following

```
[Config]
ImageList=images_off.bmp
ServiceCheckInterval=1
ServiceGlyphRunning=13
ServiceGlyphPaused=14
ServiceGlyphStopped=15
TrayIconAllRunning=16
TrayIconSomeRunning=17
TrayIconNoneRunning=18
ID={wampserver}
AboutHeader=WAMP5
AboutVersion=Version 2.2

[AboutText]
WampServer Version 2.2

Maintainer / Upgrade / Roadmap by Herve Leclerc (herve.leclerc@alterway.fr)

Powered by Alter Way [www.alterway.fr]

Sources are available at SourceForge

[www.wampserver.com]

[Services]
Name: wampapache
Name: wampmysqld

[Messages]
AllRunningHint=WAMP5 - All services running - server Offline
SomeRunningHint=WAMP5 - %n of %t services running - server Offline
NoneRunningHint=WAMP5 - None of %t services running - server Offline

[StartupAction]
Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp1/bin/php/php5.4.3/php-win.exe";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "c:/wamp1/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
```

You will need to update the StartupAction portion with your correct paths and PHP version.  After updating save it and run the wamp manager again.  It should start.

Original threads: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,126657

Wamp broke for me during the Windows Update kb3194496 on September 30th 2016.

Comment: Upgrade to WAMPServer 3 `WAMP5` is now so ancient it needs a zimmer frame

Comment: PS: That second link is not a valid link, I think we must have deleted that thread for some reason

Comment: This is wampserver 3.0.0 64bit - saying that I would actually recommend moving to docker or vagrant.  I just happen to have legacy projects that haven't made the leap.  I've also removed the second link - ty!