# How to fix my Wamp 3.0.9 server issue of Aestan Tray Menu error?

Tags: php, wampserver

I tried to run my wamp server 3.0.9, but It does not work with this error message.
[image]

I did try to solve this issue with many answers like as;
[Aestan Tray Menu Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122679/aestan-tray-menu-error)
[How to solve Wampserver Aestan Tray Menu error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998368/how-to-solve-wampserver-aestan-tray-menu-error)

I setup all of VC redist packages; vcredist_x64(2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015,2017). But I can't resolve this issue. Please let me know any ideas.

Comment: Just do a little more research: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034252/aestan-tray-menu-error-wamp-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `wampmanager.exe` that is the icon in the system tray is still a 32bit app, you also need all the 32bit MSVC Runtimes installed as well.

Remember, 64bit Windows will run 32 bit apps quite happily, therefore installing these is not a waste as you may find other apps that need these runtimes as well.

If you look at the bottom of this page [WampServer backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) you will see they have provided a single installer for all the MSVC Runtimes. So you can install all of the MSVC Runtimes in one simple installer.

You may get a dialog for those runtimes you already have installed, just click REPAIR for those.

> Small Note: The first things the install does is throw a dialog telling you that these runtime libraries are required.
>
> And if you did forget to install the MSVC runtimes before installing WAMPServer,it is best to uninstall WAMPServer and the reinstall it once you are sure all the runtimes have been installed

Comment: I have done yet, but can't run it. Is this config issue? I upgraded "wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10.exe" file with "wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.9.exe" file. Reason? ~ Thx

Comment: I know of no reasons why the 3.0.9 upgrade should cause problems. Was everything running happily before the upgrade to 3.0.9 done?

Comment: I installed x86 MSVC runtime, but my Wamp wasn't run. so uninstall it, and re-setup a file. At present, it's running without issue.

Comment: Ah yes. its always best to install the MSVC runtimes Before installing WAMPServer.

Comment: Can't see a single installer, just a zip containing a bunch of installers for each runtime version.. am I being blind?

Comment: No, unzip the installer into multiple MSVC version installers. Run them one at a time